# Error loading my web app after deploying .NET Core console app to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, pipeline

My app is running locally without any issue but when I try to run it from Azure console I have the following error :

> An error occurred while starting the application.
> SqlException: Cannot open server 'Server-name' requested by the login. Client with IP address 'w.x.y.z' is not allowed to access the server. To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run `sp_set_firewall_rule` on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range. It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect.
> `Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)`
>
> SqlException: Cannot open server 'server-name' requested by the login. Client with IP address 'ip' is not allowed to access the server. To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule

I have added IP in firewall setting on azure portal still the issue is happening

Comment: You're talking about a web app and a console app. What's the structure? Also, Azure apps might use one of a list of IP addresses, depending on the Azure region you're hosting your application in. Is the server name correct? Did you add _all_ IP addresses for your app service / function app / virtual machine? Why does this question have the tag [tag:pipeline]? Please provide us with more (relevant) information to enable us to help you. Please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 1):

This error was caused because your IP was not added in the SQL server tab(azure portal). So you must add the IP address of your SQL Server on Azure portal

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the settings of the "Firewalls and virtual networks" of your SQL Server.

Browse to your SQL Server, add the IP address and allow other azure services and resources to access the server. Refresh and wait at least 5 minutes before trying again.

I also had my ubuntu server firewall blocking my request once, so be sure your webserver is not responsible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling this setting?[image]